# Continue typing in command line after executing an option

Tags: windows, command-line

Noob question: (I don't know if this is the same for everything as it is for SASS), but after typing `sass --watch sass:css` it says `Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.`, as expected, which is nice and fine, except the command line won't let me type anything *after* that. (I also wish to type `sass --style compressed sass:css`) I've tried <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, etc., but it stays on a thick, underlined cursor similar to the one when you press <kbd>Insert</kbd>. I'm a total command line noob, just started using SASS today. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
sass --style compressed --watch sass:css
```

?

Both `--style compressed` and `--watch` are options that can be passed into `sass`. Depending on the program, most options that start with `-` or `--` or `/` don't care about the order of the options. I expect the following to also be valid:

```
sass --watch --style compressed sass:css
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. :) For those reading in the future, just a small note, it should be `compressed`, not `compress`.

Comment: @Jacedc Thanks, I updated my answer! You should also be able to edit your original question (which is where I copied `compress` from ;) )